# Restore button is required when auto-renewable subscription used In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I used `auto-renewable` `subscription` in my app. All things working perfectly but if user delete app from `iPhone` and again install then how to know that user is already subscribed or not?

we have to store user data or server or not?

I refer some questions like it , they says `Apple` reject that app which use restore button with `auto-renewable` `In-App-Purchase`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They reject apps that does NOT have the restore button. Every app that provides non_consumable or auto_renewable_subscription purchases MUST have it. They also provide everything you need in order to actually restore user purchases at SKPaymentQueue without having to store it somewhere else.

`SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()`

Which will trigger the method:

`func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`

from

`SKPaymentTransactionObserver`

I recommend this guide, everything there works very well: https://hackernoon.com/swift-how-to-add-in-app-purchases-in-your-ios-app-c1dc2fc82319

Also don't forget to add your Items ID before asking for purchases history.

Comment: here apple automatically store last purchase receipt in device ?

Comment: and after that to get all last purchase receipt data I've to simply call 'receiptValidation' function ..and it's done

Comment: `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` will give you transactions, and for each of them you can verify .transactionState, then you can iterate looking for .restored.

Comment: Restoring of non-consumable purchases and auto-renewable subscriptions are handled by the system. And if you have server to handle states of the application the Restore button will do nothing. Please take a look on this document https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html

Answer (score 2):

you should keep a restore button.

The receipt will tell you that subscribed or not and u can validate this with your server. For info

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

There you have to check **latest_receipt_info** key, that will be array of json then u read last object and check **expires_date** key.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW2

Comment: means when user delete app and again install I've to call [ https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt ] API & some where on server store receipt data & expiry date on perticular userid

Comment: Yes validation should happens on server side only, restore option will give you existing purchase info  for your apple id.. for example you subscribing one product in one device with your id and you are buying new device there you can access old purchase by using restore.no need to buy again

Comment: You can check the below link                                           
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014795-CH1-BEST_PRACTICES-PROVIDE_A_UI_FOR_RESTORING_PRODUCTS